# Angular 4 (click) changes the class of element on another component

Tags: angular

I have one root component. One root component has **3 child** component:

In `PressComponent` I have a button with `(click)="changeColors())"`.

In `CalcComponent` I have a box with blue background.

In `PianoComponent` I have a box with red background.

**How can I do this:**

When I **click** on button in `PressComponent` then:

In `CalcComponent` box will get the class `.calc-box-green`.

In `PianoComponent` box will get the class `.piano-box-yellow`.

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/d0Ll0HzU2UYq1xyi2V9L?p=preview)

Comment: use service for this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/bpl3vje178GsFIIMU7m5?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can use Output/Input like described [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) . But the service approach in the Abdul Rafay's comment can be most suited to your needs. It's up to you.

Forked plunker of Output/Input proposal of solution [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xet7z6lDc8skHITjyKDp?p=preview)

I added an @Output to the PressComponent, so it can emit the fact that the button has been pressed to the AppComponent.

```
// in PressComponent
@Output() pressed: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
changeColors() {
    this.pressed.emit(true);
}

// in App Template
<app-press (pressed)=onPressed($event)></app-press>
// in AppComponent
onPressed = (pressed) => {
    this.pressed = pressed;
}
```

Then the AppComponent forward the pressed-status to CalcComponent and PianoComponent via @Input and use the "inputed" boolean to conditionnaly apply css class

```
// in pianoComponent
@Input() pressed: boolean;
// in template
<div class="piano-box" [class.piano-box-yellow]="pressed"></div>
```